# SQL how can I skip repeated values on a colum

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So, following the hints that some of stackoverflow community gave to me, I've create this "database" to keep my dishes and it's ingredients. My only problem is that I would like to don't see repeated the name and the ID unnecesarily and I would like to know if there is any way to avoid it. Here is a screenshot and the code is below. Thanks

[image: and here is the screenshot.]

```
CREATE TABLE platos ( 
    id int auto_increment not null primary key, 
    name varchar(255) not null
)ENGINE=InnoDb;

CREATE TABLE ingredientes_para_platos (
    id  int auto_increment primary key,
    plato_id int not null,
    ingredientes varchar(255) not null,
    CONSTRAINT fk_ingredientes_para_platos FOREIGN KEY(plato_id) REFERENCES platos(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDb;

SELECT p.id,p.name,i.ingredientes
    FROM platos p, ingredientes_para_platos i
        WHERE p.id = i.plato_id;
```

Extra data asked: I'm using MySQL and the expected output is smth like

| ID | Name | Ingredients |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rice with chicken | Rice |
|  |  | Chicken |
| 2 | Rice with eggs and bananas | Rice |
|  |  | Eggs |
|  |  | Bananas |

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: @jarlh Ey, thanks! That's the next step on my online course of PHP and SQL

Comment: I'd have put that step as the previous one!

Comment: Please mention the DBMS that you are using i.e., Oracle, MSSQL , etc., Also post your expected output.

Comment: And please don't post pictures of text

Comment: But seeing as you mention php, note that this kind of thing is probably best resolved in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide how you like to see `ingredients` in your result.
One method is to use `group by` with `p.id` or `p.name` and use `group_concat` to merge the ingredients into one column. See https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/

```
SELECT p.id,p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(i.ingredientes)
    FROM platos p, ingredientes_para_platos i
        WHERE p.id = i.plato_id GROUP BY p.id;
```

Then you would see:

```
2 | Rice with bananas and eggs | Rice, Bananas, Eggs
1 | Rice with chicken          | Rice, Chicken
```

Comment: Know what? That's a pretty good idea!

Comment: And exactly what I was looking for, thank you a lote my mate :D

Comment: Glad to help...